# How to limit the number of customers entered Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a code where when the user enters five customers into the gridview it gives them an error saying that they should only enter 5 customers; what is happening now is that the user can any amount of customers. I added the error line but it seems I put it the wrong place because the user is still able to add more than 5.

```
for (int i = 0; i < getCustomer.items.Count; i++)
{
    if (getIssue.name[i].idNumber == Customer.name.idNumber)
    {
        ViewBag.errorMessage = "ID number already exists";
        return View(getCustomer);
    }

    if (getCustomer.items.Count >5)
    {
        viewBag.errorMessage=Error, You can only enter 5 customers at a time;
    }

}

if (name.Count == 0)
{
    nametbl.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CUSTOMERConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        name = nametbl.getName();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogWrite logWriter = new LogWrite(ex.ToString());
        ViewBag.errorMessage = "Unable to Connect to Database. Please see Log file for more Information";
        return View(getCustomer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to replace your second and third `if` statements with `else if`.

Comment: if count is more than 5 you need to return your view

Comment: @VivekShah could you give answer so I see exactly what you talking

Comment: I mean to say that in your code you are checking for itms.count>5 and adding view error .After this in next if block you are checking some variable name.Count == 0 which is not defined in this scope(atleast the code shared here) so assuming that it will be always true and the insert part will execute irrespective of you have added the error so either do a view validation or return the view after adding error, Same as below answer give by @zaitsman

Comment: the below answer still allow for more than five. is it that i'm entering the code at the wrong place and count==0 will always be equivlent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to return from command flow like so:

```
   if (getCustomer.items.Count >5)
    {
        viewBag.errorMessage=Error, You can only enter 5 customers at a time; // <=== AFTER THIS LINE
        return View(getCustomer);
    }
```

Comment: But i'm still able to enter more than 5 after adding that

Comment: @SusanJune are you saying that in your model if you debug you get 5 items? Or are you able to save 5 between multiple calls?

Comment: i'm able to add 5 items within multiple calls

Comment: @SusanJune You'd need to check your db count + the `getCustomer.items.Count` to avoid that situation